# Identity Server 4 not releasing memory

Tags: identityserver4

I have imeplemented Auth server with Dot net core 3.1 and Identity Server 4 (3.1.3) version. 
I am using ResourceOwnerPassword Grant type for token generation along with refresh token option. 
I have hosted my application in Azure app service. It is been observed that memory consumption is everyday increases instead going down eventhough application is not in use.

If anyone has come across this kind of situation please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not something we've come across in over 2 years of running it in production. Can you expland a bit on how your data persistence works and anything that may be non-standard?

Comment: I am just creating token through Auth server and have access token life span of 30 minutes and have refreshtoken with sliding expiration. I have not implemented persisted grant store. Using IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, IClientStore, IResourceStore to generate and validate token. Please let me know if any specific setting required to dispose the object explicitly.

Comment: Are you using the in memory stores? If so I'd expect some memory growth but the data being stored is not particularly large in nature. Also FYI using in memory is not recommended for real world use and just exists to get you up and running quickly.

Comment: I am not using in memory store. Data is being validated and populated from database. Also one thing the memory issue is more experience on azure app services. I was running it on VM since last year but didn't observed.